# WatchOS - complication update from iOS

Tags: swift, watchos, apple-watch-complication

Is there a way how to update watch complication from iOS app? I've found some solutions but nothing works for me. I need to change the text in the complication to the text inside iOS app whenever I touch my button inside the iOS app. Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

> Use the Watch Connectivity framework to send the update to the watch by calling your WCSession object’s transferCurrentComplicationUserInfo: method. This method sends a high priority message to your WatchKit extension, waking it as needed to deliver the data. As soon as the watch receives the data, it calls your session delegate’s session:didReceiveUserInfo: method. In this method, update your complication data using the provided user info dictionary, and then call your data source’s reloadTimelineForComplication: or extendTimelineForComplication: method to update your timeline.

From [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ManagingComplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH28-SW1)
More details in [this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/218/) 2016 WWDC session.

But pay attention that number of such pushes is limited to 50 in watchOS3.